# Can not create and listing file from sub-directory using Android SAF - ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: android, scoped-storage

In my app, I did code for selecting a directory with persistence permission using android `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. I did everything successfully, but the problem is I can not create a file inside the sub-directory and cannot get a list of files from the sub-directory. It gives me errors like `Permission Denial: writing com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri`

but according to [android official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory), it says `Your app can then access any file in the selected directory and any of its sub-directories.`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSION_CODE);
```

in `onActivityResult`

```
if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
    
    if (resultData != null) {
        
        Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
        final int takeFlags = resultData.getFlags()
                & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags);

        
        if(DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, treeUri).findFile("backup") == null){
        
            Uri backupDirUri = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, treeUri)
                                .createDirectory("backup").getUri();
            
            //this statement gives me error
            DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, backupDirUri)
            .createFile("text/plain", "34234234.txt")
            .getUri();
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose an app user select a directory inside SDcard named with `MyFolder` then I have created a directory `backup` inside `MyFolder` but I can not create a file inside the `backup` directory using the `backup` directory URI.

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION);` Remove all those flags. They make no sense. YOU cannot grant anything here.

Comment: please see `createFile` method. I'm calling it with created `backup' directory URI.

Comment: Ok. Which statement gives you that error message?

Comment: createBackupFile(backupDirUri, "34234234.txt");

Comment: You have a lot of code in that function. Concatenating many function calls. The question was which statement/call causes the error. If you concatenate a lot of call its hard to tell which call exactly does it. Please split function in several calls to find out.

Comment: See my updated question. At last statement of `onActivityResult`

Comment: `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, backupDirUri)
            .createFile("text/plain", "34234234.txt")
            .getUri();` Those are three calls concatenated. Which of those three produces the error was my question. Split them to find out. Or post the logcat if that tells it.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason using `getUri()` on a `DocumentFile` instance and then attempt to create another `DocumentFile` from that `Uri` fails.

Solution: don't attempt to operate on a `Uri`. Work with the `DocumentFile` instance.

The first call to `fromTreeUri` must be using an `Uri` or `Uri` from `String`. But from that point create new files by using the returned `DocumentFile`.

For example, you can try this:

```
if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
    
    if (resultData != null) {
        
        Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
        final int takeFlags = resultData.getFlags()
                & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags);

        DocumentFile root = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, treeUri);
        
        if (root.findFile("backup") == null) {
        
            DocumentFile backupDirUri = root.createDirectory("backup");
            
            // this statement should not give error now
            DocumentFile f = backupDirUri.createFile("text/plain", "34234234.txt");
            
            // Write to your just created file.
            // openOutputStream with f.getUri() will work at this point.
            // For this example, plain OutputStream to write bytes,
            // wrap it with writers or something more functional.
            OutputStream os = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(f.getUri());
            os.write("It works!".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It's not only that going back and forward from `DocumetFile` to `Uri` then to `DocumentFile` again is very inefficient if done in the same function call, but that it always fails.

**Why it fails?**

Well... sorry, I don't know. I just know that in my test devices it fails. I don't know why.

You can safely going from `Uri` to `DocumentFile` in future iterations, or with files that already exists in the file system (I mean, not just created during that same function call).

You cannot go from `Uri` to `DocumentFile` if you just created a file during that same function call. But you can safely operate on the returned `DocumentFile` of the just created file. That's why you must remember the returned `DocumentFile`, not its `Uri`, if you plan to immediately operate on that just created file.

If you just want to operate on the file at a later time, then you can save the `Uri`. And you probably want to remember it, because I'm not sure of what happens to a `DocumentFile` instance once the app is suspended then resumed. In that case, `Uri` may be safer. Also the string representation of a `Uri` is what you can save to preferences or any kind of data base/custom file.

But again, if you want to immediately do something with the created file, don't try to get its `Uri` and then create a `DocumentFile`. Just use the `DocumentFile` you already got.

To me, it looks like `DocumentFile.createDirectory` and `DocumentFile.createFile` returns before the device file system is updated. This is a guess. I still has to hear the true explanation.

That would explain why you can operate with the returned `DocumentFile` instance, of a just created child file/directory, but if you save the `Uri` and try to call any `DocumentFile` function that accepts an `Uri`, with the `Uri` of a just created file/directory, then it fails.

Another possibility is that you cannot create a second `DocumentFile` while another refers to the same uri. Remember that you may not have references to it, but it exists until garbage collection.